# NodeJS - how to scrape ld+json data and save it to an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ld

I've been trying to find a way to get the apllication/ld+json contents and saving it to a local object. What I want to have is save it to an object, and in my program I would be able to console.log(data.offers.availability) which will result in logging: "InStock", and this for each of the data values.

I currently have this:

```
            let content = JSON.stringify($("script[type='application/ld+json']").html())
            let filteredJson = content.replace(/\\n/g, '')
            let results = JSON.parse(filteredJson)
            console.log(results)
```

Which results in this: - Doesn't let me console.log(results.offers.availability)

```
 {    "@context": "http://schema.org/", 
   "@type": "Product",    "name": "Apex Legends - Bangalore - Mini Epics",
    "description": "&lt;div class=&quot;textblock&quot;&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;h2&gt;Apex Legends - Bangalore - Mini Epics &lt;/h2&gt;&lt;p&gt;Helden uit alle uithoeken van de wereld strijden voor eer, roem en fortuin in Apex Legends. Weta Workshop betreedt the Wild Frontier en brengt Bangalore met zich mee - Mini Epics style!&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Verzamel alle Apex Legends Mini Epics en voeg ook Bloodhound en Mirage toe aan je collectie!&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;",
"brand": {
        "@type": "Thing",
        "name": "Game Mania"    
},
"aggregateRating": {        
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "5",
        "ratingCount": "2"    
},
"offers": {        
        "@type": "Offer",
        "priceCurrency": "EUR",
        "price": "19.98",        
        "availability" : "InStock"    
   }
}
```

Data im trying to scrape and save:
[image]

Comment: Uh, don't use `JSON.stringify`? Also I would recommend `.text()` over `.html()` to get no escaped entities.

Comment: @Bergi: Interestingly I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input` when using `.text()` with my sample code, it works with `.html()` or the way I did it though. `.text()` seems to return an empty string.

Comment: @eol What DOM implemenation are you using in node, what is `$`? I remember a problem where some browsers would not have text content for a script. But no matter what, both `.html()` and `.text()` return strings, and `JSON.stringify()` is wrong. To remove the linebreaks, replace `/\n/g` not `/\\n/g`.

Comment: I'm using cheerio. After some debugging I found the following line: https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio/blob/main/lib/static.js#L102. According to this, they don't descend/recur if the current element's tagName is `script` and as a result an empty string will be returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Bergi pointed out, the problem is that you're using `JSON.stringify` on the content which is already a string, but out of curiosity I tried this myself. Consider the following test:

**index.html** (that is served through localhost:4000):

```
<html>
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Product",
        "name": "Apex Legends - Bangalore - Mini Epics",
        "offers": {
            "@type": "Offer",
            "priceCurrency": "EUR",
            "price": "19.98",
            "availability": "InStock"
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
<h2>Index</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

**NodeJS-script:**

```
const superagent = require('superagent');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

(async () => {
    const response = await superagent("http://localhost:4000");

    const $ = cheerio.load(response.text);
    // note that I'm not using .html(), although it works for me either way
    const jsonRaw = $("script[type='application/ld+json']")[0].children[0].data; 
    // do not use JSON.stringify on the jsonRaw content, as it's already a string
    const result = JSON.parse(jsonRaw);
    console.log(result.offers.availability);
})()
```

`result` now is an object that holds the data from the script tag and logging `result.offers.availability`, will print `InStock` as expected.

Comment: Hey! Thanks a lot for taking your time and helping me. This worked on other sites which also use application/ld+json. However on this site (which the question is based on) it got an error (undefined:5), purely because of the description content was too long and had spaces in it. It was easily fixed by adding "jsonRaw2 = jsonRaw.replace(/\n/g, '')" and then parsing jsonRaw2.